# Array of pointers evaluation

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone please tell me how would we evaluate the inner loop pointer: `*++argv[0]`.

How does it end up getting the second character from the argument?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-') {

        while ((c = *++argv[0])) {
            switch (c) {
                ....
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some kind of compelling reason to write code you don't understand?  Just don't, that is never necessary.

Comment: The best fix for this sort of code is to use POSIX [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html)
or the GNU [`getopt_long()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options) functions.

Comment: @HansPassant yes yes. Maybe some other time. =)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the info, I'm quite new to c, so I end up asking silly questions when I hit the wall of pointers.

Comment: I didn't say, and wouldn't say now, that the question is silly.  The code is fairly traditional argument parsing code by the looks of it, but that doesn't make it good code, or easy to read and understand.  It isn't easy to read or understand, though after enough exposure to such code, it becomes comprehensible (and recognizable).  In five years time, it won't be so hard.  It still won't be particularly good code; it would be better to use the functions instead.  They hide the gory details for you.

Comment: Indeed, before simple variable pointers used to look unfamiliar as well, but after codding on a simple application for a while I just got used to it, I bet it's the same with everything else. =) Well thanks for the info again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array subscript operator has higher precedence than the prefix ++ and the dereference operator. The latter two operators have the same precedence and are evaluated from right to left. The expression in the second while loop is equivalent to:

```
*(++(argv[0]))
```

The pointer to the string is obtained using the array subscript operator, then it is incremented by one using prefix increment, it now points to the second character, and then the character is obtained using the dereference operator.